# Exam: Different Label of Parts a), b), c), instead of (a), (b), (c)

Tags: exam

The title basically already says it: Does anyone of you know of a ‘simple’ way to change the label of parts in the Exam document class? I am looking for a), b), c) instead of (a), (b), (c), etc..

I unfortunately have no idea and also after some research did not find a convenient solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine the command `\partlabel`:

```
\renewcommand{\partlabel}{\thepartno)}
```

You'll find a lot more information about customizing the numbers on pages 39-40 of [the exam class documentation](https://math.mit.edu/%7Epsh/exam/examdoc.pdf).